# Listen to undo/redo event in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, contenteditable

Is there a way to listen on all the ways a user could trigger an undo on a contenteditable div? For example when the user hits Control+Z, Right-click -> Undo, or in the file menu Edit -> Undo.

I'm not looking for undo/redo algorithms or implementations, just the ability to listen to the event and overwrite the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get `event.inputType` of `input` event. Check for `"historyUndo"` / `"historyRedo"`:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
div.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  switch(e.inputType){
    case "historyUndo": alert("You did undo"); break;
    case "historyRedo": alert("You did redo"); break;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>
```

In recent browsers, you can cancel the event using the `beforeinput` event (not in Firefox yet):

```js
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
div.addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
  switch(e.inputType){
    case "historyUndo": e.preventDefault(); alert("Undo has been canceled"); break;
    case "historyRedo": e.preventDefault(); alert("Redo has been canceled"); break;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">Hello world!</div>
```

References:

- `InputEvent` specification and other `inputType` values: https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#interface-InputEvent-Attributes
- Browser compatibility for `beforeinput`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_htmlelement_beforeinput_event

Comment: Keep in mind that since this only works with the `input` event, it will not trigger unless the user's action actually changed the value of the input. For example, if the user presses ctrl+z when there is nothing to undo, this listener will not fire, even though the user did indeed attempt an undo. This isn't so much a way to listen for the user attempting to make undos, and moreso just a way to listen for _actual, successful_ undo operations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Ctrl+Z/Y is possible, but I don't know about the Right-click->Undo/Redo part.

```js
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var thisKey = e.which;

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (thisKey == 90) alert('Undo');
        else if (thisKey == 89) alert('Redo');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Already implemented the undo functionality in another way, but I thought it'd be cool to be able to do it with ctrl+z. Thanks, mate, worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Control z example at [How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

for rightclick you can show a div on a right click [How can I capture the right-click event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

then when they click the undo option on the div. just put in a onclick function.