# Listen for all ways a user might attempt to perform an undo

Tags: javascript, html, dom, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to run code every time the user attempts to make an undo. For example, the user might use a keyboard shortcut like ctrl+z, they might right click and select "Undo" from a context menu, they might tap the "undo" button on a mobile keyboard, etc. There are many ways a user can make an undo command, and I'd like to listen to all of them.

I found [this practically identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319723/listen-to-undo-redo-event-in-contenteditable-div) but the answer will not work for my use case because it listens strictly for the `input` event - which only fires when the user's undo attempt *actually modifies the content of an input element.* I don't want my code to only run when the user makes a successful undo on an input element - I want it to run every time they *attempt* an undo, whether it actually resulted in a change or not.

Currently I'm simply listening for ctrl+z and the "Undo" `event.key` value that's described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values#editing_keys) in a `keydown` event listener. The problem with this is that users may have changed their keyboard shortcut from ctrl+z to something else, they may attempt an undo from the right-click context menu, some mobile keyboard implementations may show "undo" buttons which do not fire key events at all, or many other potential situations which I'm not aware of but of which I'm sure there are many.

I know there are `cut`, `copy`, and `paste` events that allow you to do exactly what I'm looking for in those situations, but nothing like that seems to exist for undos or redos.

Comment: *The problem with this is that users may have changed their keyboard shortcut from ctrl+z to something else* ... how likely do you think this is for the average of your users? I'd wager that it hovers around 0%.

Comment: The answer you linked describes all possibilities to implement what you ask for. Regarding you "what if the user changed his key bindings" argument: If you don't know _how the user attempts to undo an action_ it is just _impossible_ to react to it because you never know _if it really was_ an undo attempt. This means that - if you don't want to trust that users use `CTRL + Z` for an undo - all you can do is _reacting to a changed value_, regardless of the _cause for that change_. The way to do it is described in the answer you already found.

Comment: "all possibilities to implement what you ask for" - what makes you so sure? The linked question only gives one potential solution - why are you so confident that it's the only one in existence? And it's not that I "don't want to trust that ctrl+z is an undo" - it's that there are many more ways to perform an undo than simply ctrl+z and I'd like to be able to notice all of them. Did you even read my question? You seem much more interested in convincing me to give up than you do in actually answering the question.

Comment: I assume a solution is possible using a combination of the `input` event + `InputEvent.inputType` mixed with `execCommand("insertText")` to make sure the undo stack always has at least one (meaningless) item in it. The only reason I'm hesitent to go that route though is because `execCommand()` was recently deprecated - although no alternative has been added to the specifications. But basically I'm just commenting this here to show that it _can_ be done, even though you say it's impossible. I just hope for a cleaner solution.

Comment: .......why was this question closed? It is not ambiguous, does not lack focus, and is very clear in what it is asking for. What part of "I want to be able to run code every time the user attempts to make an undo" is not clear?? I explained exactly what I wanted to do, I explained exactly what I tried, and I explained exactly how and why the things I tried didn't work. What more do you want? I wait 20 hours for an answer to my question only to get two snarky comments from people who didn't even read what I wrote and then find out my question is closed? Annoying.