# Get right-clicked element JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, right-click

I want to get my `<li>` element that when i right-click on it: a customized contextual menu appears, and i want to do my treatment over my initially selected element `<li>`. I've tried this `$(this).attr("id");` but it returns an item of my contextual menu and not my original right-clicked `<li>`.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript for plain javascript.

Comment: Does seem to work for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ASwjf/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To detect right click you can use,

**jquery code**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#rClick').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**html code**

```
<ul>
<li id="rClick">AAAAAA</li>
<li id="rClick2">BBBBBB</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think i didn't pass my message very well, When i use `$('#rClick').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            return false;
        });` it return the id of the `<ul>` _in my case_, i want exactely to get the id of the rightclicked `<il>` inside that `<ul>`

Comment: can u post your code, then we can see what's the issue in it. the code which i have posted is working correctly and it returns which <li> element is rightclicked.