# get the id attribute from the paragraph which has been right-clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that I have a text with this html markup:

```
<p id="myId">Some text <span>some other text</span></p>
```

How can I get the value of the `id` when I right-click anywhere on the paragraph?

Update:

I'm just passing the value to a function, which I do not mention so as to not complicate it.

Comment: take a look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783966/get-right-clicked-element-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write a mousedown handler for `p` then

```
$('p').on('mousedown', function(e){
    if(e.which== 3){
        alert(this.id)
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/36mpM/)

Comment: @RajeshPaul why not get all `p` elements using `getElementsByTagName` then register the `onmousedown` handler to it

Comment: Where should I do it???
I will be previleged if you kindly show it in your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function:

```
 $('#myId').on('mousedown',function(event) {
if(event.which == 3){
    var i = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(i);
}

});
```

event.which() reports 1,2,or 3 depending on which button was clicked.
Read here mode details http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript version:

```
var myp = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i =0;i < myp.length;i++){
  myp[i].addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
     if(e.which == 3){
     console.log(this.id);
     }
  },false);
}
```