# How to handle long click and right click events in Backbone JS

Tags: backbone.js

We can manage click and double click events like below:

```
events: {
    "click .tree-toggler": "toggletree",
    "dblclick .doubleclick" : "doubleclickFunc"
  },

 toggletree: function(e){
     //code
  },
  doubleclickFunc : function(e){
      //code
  }
```

But I want to manage right click event and Long click event. How to handle them?

Comment: I guess there is no "longclick" event defined, so you will have to write a custom event handler which can be created using the mousedown and mouseup events in combination.
As for the right click take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

Comment: @Phoenix - Yeah I have searched the doc and so many sites but couldn't find the longclick event. Have to write custom event handler.

Comment: Take a look at the 6th example in the [`$.on()` reference page](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know about the "long click" event (I didn't even know there was one and can't find some doc on it), but anyway. Backbone uses jQuery's `on` method to bind your events to the DOM. That means anything that works with `on` will work with `Backbone.View.events` (unfortunately there are some limits to the selector you specify, but apart from that).

Try:

```
events: {
  contextmenu: 'onRightClick'
},
onRightClick: function() {
  alert('it works!');
}
```

Comment: be sure to call event.preventDefault() to stop the context menu from popping up!

Comment: @jakee depends on what he wants to do, so I'd rather not say anything about it and consider that OP knows what he's doing anyway :)

Comment: Right click event is working perfectly. +1 for the right click event.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `contextmenu` event to detect right clicks as described in the earlier answer. Another way to detect clicks for the right mouse button is jquery's [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/):

```
clickTree: function(e) {
  if (event.which === 3) {
    // handle right clicks
    this.showtreemenu(e);
    return;
  }
  // handle left clicks
  this.toggletree(e);
}
```

For long clicks, aka measuring click duration, use `mouseup` and `mousedown`:

```
events: {
  'mousedown .measure-click-duration': 'clickStarted',
  'mouseup .measure-click-duration': 'clickEnded'
},

clickStarted: function(e) {
  this.clickStartTime = e.timeStamp;
},

clickEnded: function(e) {
  var clickDuration = e.timeStamp - this.clickStarted;
  if (clickDuration > 1000) {
    this.longClick(e);
  }
}
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHvhc/1/) demonstrating `contextmenu` for right clicks and the click duration described above.