# How to append javascript varible without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I've simple javascript function mentioned below:

```
<script>
    function getValue(val)
    {
      document.getElementById('answer').value = val;
    }
</script>
```

This function get's called on click of span and returned value gets displayed in input text.
I've three questions:

1] On click of span, if I want to append current value of varible 'val' with previous value; and return appended value to calling function. can you please suggest, how to achieve same without using jQuery?

2] There is one span which is suppose to work like Backspace. So click of span, i want to remove last character from `document.getElementById('answer')`.value  [This also without using jQuery]

3] There is one span which is suppose to work like Navigation keys [Right & Left]. So click of span [Let's say right], i want to move cursor position of the input text one character right and similarly for Left [This also without using jQuery]

Can you please suggest some pointers to achieve this?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Please help me in figuring out the connection between these two topics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your question 1 I think you can do below. Code not tested**

```
function getValue(val)
{
var currentVal = document.getElementById('answer').value
if(currentVal.length > 0 )
  currentVal = parseInt(currentVal);
      document.getElementById('answer').value = currentVal + val;
}
```

**For question 2 :**

Get the value and then do string operation to remove the last char. Its easy little google search for the string operations

**For question 3 :**

you can use event oncontextmenu for right click. Example below.

[How can I capture the right-click event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

For moving cursor check below

[Set keyboard caret position in html textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox)

Comment: Thanks for providing pointers for all three questions.

Answer (score 1):

- `+=` oprator appends string to existing string(not applicable in this case).
- use return keyword to return updated value.
- for removing last character use substring.

so try:

```
function getValue(val)
{
  var currentText = document.getElementById('answer').value;
  var updatedText = currentText.substring(0,currentText.length-2) +  val;
  document.getElementById('answer').value = updatedText;
  return updatedText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zaheer ; this is very much useful.