# How to jquery add class to div on Rightclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Left Click**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "div" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "class-one" );
     //alert('left click');
    });
});
```

**Right Click**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "div" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "class-two" );
     //alert('Right Click');
    });
});
```

it's my requirement Jquery Mouse left click add one class and mouse right click add another class, so my task left click add class is done and right click add class is Not working,

If you possible on right click on Jquery ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript

Comment: duplicate of so many questions..just do a google search..or a SO search..

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Kn9s7/5/   or    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery/2725963#2725963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way:

HTML --

```
<div id="test">
    test test
</div>
```

CSS --

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #99EAEA;
}

.class-one {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}

.class-two {
    background-color: #EA3355;
}
```

JQUERY --

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    document.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; };

    $("#test").click(function() {
      $( this ).removeClass("class-two").addClass("class-one");
    });

    $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
        if( e.button == 2 ) { 
            $("#test").removeClass("class-one").addClass("class-two");
            return false; 
        } 
        return true; 
    });  
});
```

that's it! Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ag62dyry/1/

Comment: it's right answer, i use this so again one problem windows right click not working,

Answer (score 2):

The event name for right-click is `contextmenu`:

```
$("div").on("contextmenu", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("class-two");
});
```

Comment: Yup, this is the right way for jQuery 1.7+. PS you forgot the closing `)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").mousedown(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("class-two");
        if (e.button == 2) {
            alert('Right mouse!');
            //here goes the code you want to add in mouse right click
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```