# Right click event is not recognised

Tags: javascript, jquery

A Jquery click event is not fired with the right mouse button, only with the left one! Is there an explanation and a solution for that?

```
<textarea name="message"  id="message"></textarea>

$("#message").on('click', function(event) { 
     alert("ok");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f29vuwoL/

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript#answer-4236294

Comment: **The `click` event is only fired when the left mouse button is clicked.** As stated by @tymeJV use `mousedown` which applies to all three buttons, then distinguish with `e.which` as he explains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* combine the `click` and `contextmenu` events into one listener:

```
$("#message").on('click contextmenu', function(event) { 
    alert("ok");
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f29vuwoL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mousedown` to detect all mouse events, then use `event.which` to determine which mouse button was pressed (1,2,3 = left, middle, right respectively)

```
$("#message").on('mousedown', function(e) { 
    alert(e.which);
});
```