# Creating a custom context menu on right click. jquery

Tags: jquery, html, contextmenu, right-click

I have two columns, and two inputs, made to create new content that will be placed in any of those columns.

One input is to enter the content of the div *(and assign the class="item")*, the second input is for entering the *class* for that content *(for styling)*.

So, I want to be able to open a *custom context menu* when I **right-click** on any of the *items* I have created. (Bit of a problem to me). With jQuery.

Can you help come through this, please.

**html**

```
<div id="ctxtmen" class="invisible">
    <ul>
        <li>Edit</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the **jQuery.js**

```
$(".item").mousedown(function(e){ 

  if( e.which == 3 ) { 
    $("#ctxtmen").removeClass("invisible").css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
  }

$(document).click(function(){

  $("#ctxtmen").addClass("invisible");
  if( e.which == 2 ){
    $("#ctxtmen").addClass("invisible");
  }
});

$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(x){

  if (!$("#ctxtmen").hasClass("invisible")) {
    x.preventDefault();    
  }   
});  

});
```

Check out the: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FYPs89/cd9pvhsz/13/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I capture the right-click event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Comment: Checking them out, thanks.

Comment: You are adding a lot event handlers inside another handler which is not the right way

Comment: The `click` and `bind` events should be out of `mousedown`

Comment: Check out this article: [5 jQuery Right Click Context Menu Plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/right-click-context-menu-plugins/)