# Distinguish between left and right click inside onclick function

Tags: javascript

I need really fast answer. How to distinguish between left and right click inside a function. Code looks like this:

```
<p onclick="FuncOnClick()">
```

```
function FuncOnClick() {
//how to do distinguish?
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I capture the right-click event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this. Using the HTML onclick does not work for right click. But adding the event listener in Javascript instead does seem to work.

```js
document.getElementById('click').onmousedown = FuncOnClick;

function FuncOnClick(event) {
  console.log(event.which);
  switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
      alert('Left');
      break;
    case 3:
      alert('Right');
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="click">test</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :-

```js
    $('#mouseClick').mousedown(function(event) {
      switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
          alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
          break;
        case 2:
          alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
          break;
        case 3:
          alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
          break;
        default:
          alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="mouseClick">Click here</p>
```