# Cannot catch right click event?

Tags: javascript

When click event is fired with "right button" it is not caught by "else if" in in the "select" function. Most annoying thing is that it is caught in any other sample pages that I made earlier. Please help me in debugging this problem.

```
document.addEventListener('click' ,this.select.bind(this) ,false);

Filesystem.prototype.select = function(event){
    if(event.button === 0){
         // Code that's working fine
    }
    else if(event.button === 2){
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: How about change `else if(event.button === 2)` to `else` and `alert(event.button)` to see whats going on?

Comment: Or just `console.log(event);` to inspect the whole event object...

Comment: Put `console.log(event);` before the `if` would be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I capture the right-click event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript)

Comment: fuyushimoya , I tried your way but then i saw that select function is not even fired of right click 'on my page'.

Comment: I think what Tushar post is just what you're finding.

Comment: One thing more , it is working on mozilla but not on chrome

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you cannot intercept right click using click event. Instead, use mousedown or contextmenu.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0rd5dc3v/5/.

```
var select = function(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.button === 0){
         // Code that's working fine
    }
    else if(event.button === 2){
        alert("hello");
    }
}

document.getElementsByClassName('click')[0].addEventListener('click' ,select,false);

document.getElementsByClassName('mousedown')[0].addEventListener('mousedown' ,select,false);
```

Right click is not captured for the red square (listening for click events) but is captured for the blue square (listening for mousedown events).

Comment: When you click an element on an HTML element the object that is passed to the event handler has an attribute called 'button' which stores the integer code for the mouse button that was pressed when the event was fired. So you can catch right click with 'click' event