# Bootstrap Modal open on new page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap toggle link which will open a full screen modal windows on **left click** which will display all the information.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" href='#modal-add-contact' class='btn'>View Info</a>
```

However, sometimes when user go through the table list on the page with multiple **View Info** links, they tend to **right click** and open to **new tab**, or right click and open to **new window**.

So it end up displaying the table list of info with the *View Info* link instead of the modal window.

How can I let the new tab window load the Modal on default base on the link clicked?

Comment: Have you thought of creating a custom context menu and give an option to open in New window and then handle it using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user right clicks and opens link in tab, he will get same url with a hash tag
*www.example.com#modal-add-contact*

So if you simply

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window.location.hash).modal("show");
});
```

modal will be up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing right-clicks that an event fires up named ***oncontextmenu***?
explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript) 
You just have to manually open the **modal** dialogue using code of some **JQuery**  explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)