# Prevent text deletion in form "input" type or "textarea" element by using the context menu in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, forms

I want to prevent that the user can delete some characters entered into an input form element.

When the cursor is inside a form "input" type or "textarea" the context menu of IE 11 (activated via right mouse click) shows the entry "**Delete**". If clicked, the next character or the selected text is deleted from the form element.

*The "Cut" and "Paste" actions from the context menu can be prevented by listening to the `cut` and `paste` events and executing `event.preventDefault()`.*

How can I prevent that the user can use the "**Delete**" action. Is there an event I can subscribe to?

Comment: You can capture the contextmenu event and disable all options. Some good code examples here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround I'm currently using.