# What are all the options on react for tree view

Tags: reactjs, redux, treeview

I need to create an application. Which should have tree view. In tree only some of them are draggable.

Most importantly it should have search option.

And it should be clickable and whenever I right click I should get an event to display pop up.

Please suggest me some good Tree view examples available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree 
Refer above link for drag and search filter. It is good to handle everything
Please refer below my answer for handling click

```
  generateNodeProps={clickedNode => ({
      onClick: () => console.log(clickedNode),
  })}
```

Comment: We can make use of JS contextmenu options.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one

https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree

Good one, but I haven't found onItemClick event so Im using `addEventListener` for that like this

```
clickEventListenerAdd()
{
  function addEventListenerByClass(className, event, fn) {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var ii = 0, len = list.length; ii < len; ii++) {
      list[ii][event] = fn;
    }
  }

  addEventListenerByClass(
    'rst__rowContents',
    'onclick',
    HANDLE_FUNC
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have gone through this. But what about right click on node.

Comment: I think the same as I shown for `onclick`, but `contextmenu` event  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript