# How to correctly handle right click mouse event for a button

Tags: javascript

I want to handle mouse right-click event for my button. I wrote the following code;

```
mybutton.onmousedown = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const mouseEvent = { 
        0: () => leftClickCallback,
        2: () => rightClickCallback
    }
    mouseEvent[ e.button ]();
}
```

It works fine but it doesn't prevent the browser context menu and I have to set the "oncontextmenu" event like below to prevent the browser context menu event;

```
mybutton.oncontextmenu = e => e.preventDefault();
```

I've also tried to stop propagation of mouse event like below although it didn't work:

```
mybutton.onmousedown = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation(); // <====
        const mouseEvent = { 
            0: () => leftClickCallback,
            2: () => rightClickCallback
        }
        mouseEvent[ e.button ]();
}
```

I am wondring why I need to explicitly disable oncontextmenu event for my button.

Comment: The event `oncontextmenu` is the event that is fired when the user right clicks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235426/how-can-i-capture-the-right-click-event-in-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan no this is not my question. my question is that why `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` function in `onmousedown` doesn't prevent oncontextmenu event.

Comment: Yes, why they do not cancel the click. So it is what you are asking and the answer will be in the result list. The answer COULD be "because it doesn't"

Comment: @Seblor you mean they are two separate events which I must handle them separatly?

Comment: There is one event for the left click, and an other one for the right click. You can give them the same callback, though.

Comment: @Seblor But I thought e.button === 2 and oncontextmenu event are the same. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that the right click does 2 things. It triggers a mouseDown event, *and* opens the context menu. So you might have to catch them both.

Comment: @Seblor Hmm. Then that makes sense. Do you have any reference?

Comment: Don't forget the context menu can also be open with a keyboard button, it should have its own event. I can't find any official doc, but this question has the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Comment: @Seblor I found this that validate your assumption. [mouse events basics](https://javascript.info/mouse-events-basics). Please write a good answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right mouse button click seems to fire multiple events (though it might depend on the browser) :

- a MouseDown event, with `event.button === 2` and/or `event.which === 3`,
- a ContextMenu event.

It makes sense since the context menu can also be opened by a keyboard button (depending on your keyboard layout), or a macro.

What you can do is use the same callback. For example :

```js
function preventAll(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}

document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('mousedown', preventAll);
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('contextmenu', preventAll);
```

```html
<button id="something">test</button>
```